# cURL error 3: <url> malformed on admin

Tags: curl, laravel-5

I have been working locally on a `laravel` app and everything was great.

After migrate to my shared host (I know isnt the best idea) I started to get `cURL error 3: <url> malformed` when I try to login in my admin panel.

This is is my controller:

```
public function getTokenValue() {
    $admin = Admin::first();
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $token_uri = env('TOKEN_BALANCE_ENDPOINT');
    $token_uri =  str_replace("||contractaddress||",$admin->contract_address, $token_uri );
    $token_uri =  str_replace("||address||",$admin->ether, $token_uri );
    $token = $client->request('GET',$token_uri);
    return json_decode($token->getBody())->result;
}
```

[image: Error]
I did my research but got mixed ideas and nothing pretty clear.

Comment: What does `var_dump($token_uri);` show?

Comment: well, it is what the error says, the url supplied in $token_uri is invalid. i bet something isn't properly urlencoded, for example, the `||`'s are supposed to be encoded to `%7C%7C`, so the final url shold look like `%7C%7CCONTRACTADDRESS%7C%7C`   and `%7C%7Caddress%7C%7C`, and their contents also needs to be properly urlencoded, but something isn't..